# How can I count per year and per week the total number of times a code occurs?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I count per year and per week the total number of times a code occurs => only using column “Date” and column “Code”; so without extra “helper”- columns “Weeknumber” & “Year”.
My idea is to use only a formula, so without using pivot table, etc.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @Stefan Deckers,, without heiper value is not looking possible,, if U are comfortable with solution using a few helper column the plz confirm through comments. Also [edit] your post & add all about using helper data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("R3"& "C" & MATCH(C4,B2:R2, FALSE) +1 & ":R22" & "C" & MATCH(C4,B2:R2,FALSE) + 1,FALSE))
```

Using your data this will match whatever is in column C with the reference and return the sum from Row3 to Row 22 (modify to suit). Using different sheets you need to modify:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("sheet1!R3"& "C" & MATCH(D5,Sheet1!B2:M2, FALSE) +1 & ":R22" & "C" & MATCH(D5,Sheet1!B2:M2,FALSE) + 1,FALSE))
```

It is possible to refine further but I would need further information on the data format.

Justin

Answer (score -2):

Purfleet gave me this formula;
=COUNTIFS(DATA!$C:$C;'# Codes'!B$2;DATA!$B:$B;">="&DATE($Q$1;1;1-WEEKDAY(DATE($Q$1;1;1);2))+$A19*7;DATA!$B:$B;"<="&DATE($Q$1;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE($Q$1;1;1);2)+$A20*7-1)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9aBE.png)

I've been using the formula for some time now.

Thanks for the help.

Sincerely,

Stefan